# Infer property names from array property values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the interface

```js
interface FormField {
    name: string;
}
```

and a value such as:

```js
const fields: FormField[] = [
    { name: 'givenName' },
    { name: 'familyName' }
]
```

I would like to infer this interface:

```js
interface FormModel {
    givenName: string;
    familyName: string;
}
```

So use the array's property values as property names.

I tried something like:

```js
type Model<T extends Array<FormField>> = { [K['name'] in T]: string };
```

but this doesn't work. Is this kind of thing possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution already goes in the right direction, we can tune the types a bit up to make it work:

```
// make name generic, so we can refer to concrete string literal
interface FormField<T extends string> {
    name: T;
}

const fields = [
    { name: 'givenName' },
    { name: 'familyName' }
] as const  // const assertion to retain strings "givenName" and "familyName"

// T[number] gives all possible array values, T[number]["name"] all possible names
type Model<T extends ReadonlyArray<FormField<any>>> = { [K in T[number]["name"]]: string };

type FormModel = Model<typeof fields> // { givenName: string; familyName: string; }
```

`fields` doesn't have an explicit type `FormField[]` anymore in order to preserve literal types. If you still want to have stong type checks for `fields`, you can use a factory function:

```
const formField = <T extends string>(t: T): FormField<T> => ({ name: t })

const fields = [
  formField('givenName'),
  formField('familyName'),
  formField(3) // , error
]
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFtXAgGwBMAeAFWQgA9IRCBnZOsKUAcwD5kBvAKGX+Qg4WCAC5kpANw8Avjx4J0IJshiYceIsgC8yMhWoRaDJixAcAFGHGkAlOIzZcBEqU7bOFroOFjkYZBlbeUVlAJhNeh1kAG0+VXVnIgsAclZgADcjADlfFNsAGni1J0jU+CxgfABPXJF8ov4AeiaE0pcLAGZbZBbkQF4NwGKdngBdeTBqgAcUAFl0QgJ9KhoogCUIOEIlGoBBKCg4auJHDRdiOBBq9mvo7xiAaWRQCRiQAFcsACNoEZiAIiEIj+IxG4lMbEC0h4E2maHUcwW+GiCMWMIg6BgqkidE4fW86SyIDqfnB5kkqmEVVqvjBzDY5Lk8iAA)